# Application lags on each timer tick

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have an application that periodically pings a server to give you the latency of your connection.  From what I have read the `System.Timers.Timer` is run on a separate thread from the UI.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Start();
}
```

I have a `NotifyIcon` with a `ContextMenu` that displays the result of this ping. however I noticed that the `ContextMenu` lags every time the timer ticks and I have no idea why.

EDIT: completely forgot to add the timer_tick function

```
            var selectedServer = Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedServer;
            PingReply reply;
            switch (selectedServer)
            {
                case "NA":
                    reply = _pvpnetClient.Send("64.7.194.1");
                    break;
                case "EUW":
                    reply = _pvpnetClient.Send("95.172.65.1");
                    break;
                case "EUN":
                    reply = _pvpnetClient.Send("66.150.148.1");
                    break;
                default:
                    reply = _pvpnetClient.Send("64.7.194.1");
                    break;
            }

            if (reply == null || reply.Status != IPStatus.Success) return;
            var returnedPing = reply.RoundtripTime;

            LoLPing.Text = @"Server: " + selectedServer + @" - Ping: " + reply.RoundtripTime + @"ms";
            PingText.Text = @"Ping: " + reply.RoundtripTime + @"ms";
            if (returnedPing < 120f)
            {
                LoLPing.Icon = Properties.Resources.GreenIcon;
            }
            else if (returnedPing > 120f && returnedPing < 200)
            {
                LoLPing.Icon = Properties.Resources.YellowIcon;
            }
            else
            {
                LoLPing.Icon = Properties.Resources.RedIcon;
            }
```

Comment: What does timer_Tick() do?

Comment: Can you show us your Timer code?

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorry forgot to add that, been a long day haha.

Comment: By lag do you mean that the context menu is slow to appear or that the content in the menu is slow to update with the results?

Comment: Do favor methods like Socket.SendAsync() and Ping.SendAsync() so that a non-responsive machine isn't going to bog down your UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.100).aspx

"The server-based Timer is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment."

It doesn't automatically generate it's own thread.  If it did generate it's own thread, you'd get an exception when trying to update your control without the use of `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.

I would do this with a `BackgroundWorker` object, who's `DoWork` handler contained a loop with a `Thread.Sleep` in it.  Then do all the slow ping work there in the `DoWork` loop, and have one GUI function that takes `returnedPing` and does the icon update.  Call this GUI function with Invoke to get the GUI actions back on the GUI thread.

```
class SlowOperation
{
    BackgroundWorker m_worker;
    void StartPolling()
    {
        m_worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        m_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        m_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        m_worker.DoWork += m_worker_DoWork;
        m_worker.ProgressChanged += m_worker_ProgressChanged;
    }

    void m_worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!m_worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            int returnedPing = 0;
            // Get my data
            m_worker.ReportProgress(0, returnedPing);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    void m_worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myForm.Invoke(myForm.UpdateMyPing((int)e.UserState));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, What does the code inside `m_worker_ProgressChanged()` do?

Comment: Assuming your form/control has a function `UpdateMyPing` that changes the icon based on the numeric `returnedPing`, `m_worker_ProgressChanged` will call it on the appropriate thread.  Without the Invoke you could get some exceptions.

Comment: oh! okay, I figured that's what it did, I just didn't get what the .Invoke was calling from.  I didn't get what m_control was. Thanks for the clarification :D.

Comment: I have a question, MyForm isnt static so I can't use MyForm.UpdateMyPing. What would you suggest I change?

Comment: Add a reference to your form to the class where this is implemented, or implement this in the form itself and call the function directly.

Comment: If implemented directly in the form, the invoke like would read like `Invoke(UpdateMyPing((int)e.UserState)`

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how long the Send method of `_pvpnetClient` takes to run.

You are running a `System.Windows.Timer` (I know because of the `Tick` event), so this method will be invoked on the main thread, and it will block all GUI updates until it is done.  If you want to do the work on another thread, you could use the `System.Timers.Timer` object, but you would have to invoke back to the main thread to update the GUI elements.

Comment: That's the weird thing, if I Ping using command line, its instant. Also, there was no lag until recently. I tested it on other computers and same thing has happened, I don't know if its something I wrote that isn't optimal.